# Date dependent hours Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Hi guys what I want to do is collect the date that I put in one of the inputs and use it to charge the hours from my database: create.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha de la cita:</label>
        <div class="input-group date fecha">
    <input type="text" name="fechaInicio" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Pass it on to the controller: controllers. js:

```
$scope.getHoras = function(){
        var fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
        $http.get('../api/horas.php'),{'fechaInicio':fechaInicio}.then(function(response){
            $scope.citas = response.data;
        });
    };
```

make enquiry: hours.php:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
@session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "pruebas";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/*$sql = "SELECT hora FROM horas where $fecha and horaCompleta = '1'"*/
$sql = "SELECT hora FROM citas WHERE horaCompleta = 0 AND 'fechaInicio = $date-> fechaInicio' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     $data = array() ;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($data);
$conn->close();
?>
```

and now view the data collected in the create. html on my select field:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="hora" ng-init="getHoras()">Hora:</label>
<select ng-model="cita.hora">

<option
value="{{cita.hora}}"
ng-repeat="cita in citas">
{{cita.hora}}
</option>
</select>
```

The thing is that I want to visualize the available hours according to the date that I select in the Imput above.

visualization:
[visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGbi2.png)
horas -> hours
fecha de la cita -> date

Comment: There is a defect in the service call change like this `$http.get('../api/horas.php?fechaInicio='+$scope.cita.fechaInicio).then`

Comment: i ve try that solution but still dont work :( more ideas? I cant understand why its failing @KalaikumarThangasamy

Comment: $scope.getHoras = function(){
  var fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
  $http.get('../api/horas.php?fechaInicio=' + $scope.cita.fechaI‌​nicio).then(function(response){
   $scope.citas = response.data;
  });
 };
i dont know why stack dont let me edit the post but this is what i put